# IOS 10.0.1 on an IPhone 7 with WhatsApp 2.16.10

Tags: whatsapp.app

WhatsApp 2.16.10 update for iOS 10 now shows recent WhatsApp calls on the iPhone recent calls log, rather then just logging it in WhatsApp. Is there a way to turn this off? It's really not needed.

Answer (score 1):

WhatsApp is using the new CallKit VOIP framework that allows apps such as WhatsApp and Skype to integrate more directly with iOS. This allows, for example, incoming calls to show up on the lock screen like cell phone calls do. As you've discovered it can also integrate with the native Phone app's call history ("recents"), contacts and so forth.

There is no setting to disable this as it is a fundamental change to how iOS handles VOIP apps.